# Android Storage access framework

Tags: android, storage

I am writing a file encryption app.

I set up the file(s) browse code using the default storage directory.

This works great, I wrote the code to be able to encrypt multiple files as well as directories.

Directories simply get copied, and the files within are encrypted into a new directory.

The problem is now after some research I have found that I need to utilize the storage access framework to be able to select files from external sd cards, and any other storage system the user may have.

My question is, is there a way to select multiple files and folders simultaneously through activities in the saf?  Is there a workaround for this?  I found an activity that is able to select multiple files, and I found one that allowed me to select a single directory.

Comment: `set up the file(s) browse code using the default storage directory` ??? What are you doing there? Please explain. How did you try to select multiple directories with saf? The same way as selecting multiple files?

Comment: So do i understand correct that you want the user to be able to select AND multiple files AND multiple directories in one go? Which normal file picker can do that?

Comment: Just wrote a custom one that displays all the file names through the listFiles(); method of the File class.

Comment: Please answer my AND question to the point. Please answer all my questions.

Comment: In that code, I get the default dir through Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();  Through SAF, I tried activity ACTION_GET_CONTENT, passing Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, and setType("asterisk/asterisk").  Yes you are correct that is what I want.  I dont think there is a normal file picker that does that.

Comment: `I found an activity that is able to select multiple files, `. An Activity? You only need to know how to set up an Intent for it. So what do you have?

Comment: ACTION_GET_CONTENT is not SAF. Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); intent.setType("asterisk/asterisk"); intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLES, true): startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: You have to write your own SAF DocumentFile picker is you want to select files and directories at the same time. But i think no user is asking for such a picker.

Comment: I have not the faitest idea why you post that code. What do you want to show/tell with it?

Comment: I tried ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT too.  Doesnt allow directory selection with the rest of the code the same.

Comment: In case there is something else that needs to be included.  Perhaps a different extra or type.

Comment: To pick a directory you use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: That picker exists somewhere.  in the default file browser app, you can select multiple files and directories, mainly for deletion purposes.

Comment: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. didnt allow me to select files, and only allowed me to select a single directory.

Comment: Yes. I know that. But i asked you if EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLEScould be used. As inever tried that myself.

Comment: I did add that, but it doesn't seem to have any effects.